# ¿Como convertir un archivo de python que usa pygame a apk?

Tags: python, android, pygame, apk

Necesito convertir un archivo .py que usa pygame a apk, no se si se pueda hacer eso, porque hasta donde sé solo los archivos kivy se pueden convertir a apk, ojalá puedan ayudarme con eso.
De Antemano, gracias

Comment: Desde que Pygame 2 (SDL2) puedes generar el apk/aab con [Buildozer](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android)/pyhon-for-android similar a como se hace con Kivy. Yo solo probé estando Pygame 2 en beta y con una app simple por curiosidad, así que no se que tal funciona en casos mas complejos...

Comment: @FJSevilla Pero debo cambiar todo lo que diga kivy por pygame?, o como lo hago, porque lo intenté una vez y me marcó mil errores

Comment: No, debería funcionar con Pygame sin tener que portar nada a Kivy. Ademas, pasar de Pygame a Kivy no es trivial, son librerías completamente diferentes que básicamente solo comparten el uso de SDL2, no basta con cambiar los imports o algunas funciones/métodos/clases, hay que reescribir la app casi al completo generalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque Buildozer/p4a están enfocados en kivy, desde que PyGame paso a usar también SDL2 (PyGame 2.x) es posible usar también buildozer para generar el .apk/.aab para Android.

El proceso básico el mismo que se sigue en una app de Kivy:

- [Instalar buildozer y las dependencias necesarias](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation). Buildozer solo funciona en Linux/MacOS. Si usas Windows necesitaras usar una maquina virtual o WSL e instalar preferentemente una versión LTS de Ubuntu.
- Con todo instalado, podemos comenzar a [crear el paquete para  Android](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#init-and-build-for-android). Lo primero es abrir una terminal e ir (`cd`) al directorio raíz de tu app, donde se localice tu `main.py`. Hecho esto ejecutar

  ```
  $ buildozer init
  ```

  Esto generara un archivo `buildozer.spec` en el directorio de la app, que deberás editar para tu caso concreto (permisos, icono, dominio y nombre del paquete, etc). La diferencia principal con una app de kivy son obviamente los requisitos de la app que debes incluir, los básicos para una app de PyGame serian:

  ```
  requirements =python3,pygame,jnius,sdl2,sdl2_image,sdl2_mixer,sdl2_ttf,png,jpeg
  ```
- Tras modificar y guardar el .spec, puedes generar el paquete con:

  ```
  $ buildozer -v android debug
  ```

  o si quieres desplegar el paquete y ejecutarlo en un smartphone conectado:

  ```
  $ buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat
  ```

  La primera vez tardara bastante ya que buildozer descargara y configurara el SDK y NDK de Android. Si todo va bien generara un directorio `bin` con el nuevo paquete dentro del mismo.
- Cuando todo este listo puedes generar la versión de lanzamiento con:

  ```
  $ buildozer -v android release
  ```

Comment: Disculpa la insistencia, pero, eso se puede hacer en google colab?, o necesito la maquina virtual, porque dañe mi sistema operativo instalando ubuntu, tuve que restaurar mi pc

Comment: Hola Alberto, pues si es posible, acabo de probar con una app simple de PyGame y ningún problema.