CAMBIAR TIPO DE CELDAS A IMÁGENES EN PYGAMES
Buen día,
Actualmente me gustaría actualizar los colores de mi juego "2048" a que las celdas sean imágenes en vez del color. Adjunto las imágenes que cree para que los pueda reemplazar.

La idea es cambiar estos cuadros por esas imágenes con sombras que hice.

Actualmente tenía los colores con una tupla que le daba el color que yo les asignaba
#COLORES PARA NUMEROS
COLORS = {
0: ("#b7efc5"),
2: ("#277da1"),
4: ("#577590"),
8: ("#4d908e"),
16: ("#43aa8b"),
32: ("#90be6d"),
64: ("#f9c74f"),
128: ("#f9844a"),
256: ("#f8961e"),
512: ("#f3722c"),
1024: ("#f94144"),
2048: ("#7b2cbf"),
}
,pero tenía esta idea en mente, adjunto imagen de mi idea:

Estuve leyendo los archivos de pygames, me indica que tengo que renderizar la imagen para que pueda ser visible. Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo lo podría hacer si tengo un ciclo for que renderiza los números de la tupla que tiene colores nada más?
Este es mi código:
https://gist.github.com/Col0rblind/1895d85e6b860720afcd71bcac88bb41/e4fa5467ac4b3063513d6741afe8e5759c7660ac
Soy muy nuevo en esto del mundo de la programación para juegos. He estado investigando y corrigiendo detalles. Agradecería si pudieran orientarme que debo investigar o buscar.

Si te entendi bien, tu pregunta se reduce a "¿Cómo renderizar imagenes?" ... ¿entendi bien?

Si bro. Básicamente cambiar la renderización de colores a imágenes.

Dado que pygame.image.load() retorna una instancia de pygame.Surface, para dibujar la imagen simplemente debes usar el método pygame.surface.blit() para renderizarla sobre otra, en caso tu surface screen.
Es decir, en vez de usar pygame.draw.rect() como haces ahora para el color sólido, simplemente debes usar screen.blit() para la imagen, exactamente igual que hacías con la surface del texto.
Siempre ten presente que el frame se construye por capas, apilando surfaces unas encima de otras en el orden en el que explícitamente vamos llamando a blit. En definitiva, el orden importa
Algunas observaciones:

Es recomendable usar el método pygame.Surface.convert() sobre la surface obtenida por pygame.image.load() para homogeneizar el formato de pixel. Si el formato de pixel es el mismo en todas las surfaces el renderizado es más eficiente.

En vez de hardcodear el diccionario con las imágenes de cada casilla, puedes generarlo dinámicamente iterando sobre las imágenes del directorio.

Considera substituir pygame.font por pygame.freetype. Este módulo viene a reemplazar al primero y añade funcionalidades extra y mejora la ergonomía de uso.

Es recomendable que saques la definición de font y message_font de draw_screen(). Si no se va a modificar la fuente en cada frame y son constantes a lo largo de la ejecución mejor definirlas fuera como constantes, por eficiencia entre otras cosas.

pygame.Surface.blit() retorna una instancia de Rect que te puede ser de utilidad para posteriores operaciones, por ejemplo posicionar el texto en tu caso.


Con todo, podrías hacer algo así (solo agrego las partes nuevas o modificadas):
import pathlib      # <<<<<
import random
import sys
import pygame
import constantes


# ...

FONT = pygame.freetype.Font(None, size=60)
MESSAGE_FONT = pygame.freetype.Font(None, size=30)
TILES = {
    int(path.stem): pygame.transform.smoothscale(
        pygame.image.load(path),
        (constantes.CELL_SIZE, constantes.CELL_SIZE)
    ).convert()
    for path in pathlib.Path("assets/images/forms").glob('*.png')
}

# ...

def draw_screen():
    screen.fill(constantes.WHITE)

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            value = board[i][j]
            tile = TILES.get(value, TILES[0])
            tile_rect = screen.blit(
                tile,
                (
                    j * constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                    i * constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                ),
            )

            if value != 0:
                text_surf, text_rect = FONT.render(str(value), constantes.BLACK)
                text_rect.center = tile_rect.center
                screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)

    # condicion victoria
    if game_won:
        MESSAGE_FONT.render_to(
            draw_screen,
            (30, constantes.SCREEN_HEIGHT// 2 - 40),
            "¡GANASTE! PRESIONA 'R' PARA REINICIAR",
            constantes.RED
        )
    elif game_over:
        MESSAGE_FONT.render_to(
            screen,
            (30, constantes.SCREEN_HEIGHT// 2 - 40),
            "GAME OVER, PRESIONA 'R' PARA REINICIAR",
            constantes.RED
        )

El uso de pygame.transform.smoothscale() o pygame.transform.scale() no es necesario si tus imágenes ya tienen el tamaño exacto de cada celda y no se redimensionan al inicio o a lo largo del juego (de acuerdo al tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo, por el maximizado de la ventana, etc). En este caso, bastaría con:
TILES = {
    int(path.stem): pygame.image.load(path).convert()
        for path in pathlib.Path("assets/images/forms").glob('*.png')
}


Excelente compañero muchas gracias

¿Es recomendable colocar en mayúscula las constantes y variables en minúscula?

Por un momento pensé que era chatGPT

@CandidMoe no se si tomármelo como alago o como insulto jajaja. Por curiosidad le he pasado la respuesta a un par de detectores de contenido generado por IA y uno me ha dicho que soy un 53% IA, otros más adecuados para el español me dicen que probablemente soy humano, menos mal... Tiempos curiosos para ser alumno  y andar jugando a que mi trabajo hecho por mi no parezca generado por IA  o a que mi trabajo generado por IA parezca humano y del otro lado intentar averiguar quien quiere timarte y quién no.

@NumberBinary100 las constantes por convención de estilo se nombran usando  mayúsculas y guiones bajos para separar palabras. Las variables y nombres de funciones/métodos,  igual pero todo en minúsculas. Eso si, son solo normas de estilo, no se está obligado a seguirlas, aunque mejoran la legibilidad y mantenimiento del código, por ejemplo otro desarrollador al ver el nombre en mayúsculas asumirá que es una constante (que no existen realmente en Python) y que no debe modificarla. Puedes mirarte las convenciones establecidas en PEP 8 si te interesa el tema: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Gracias amigo. ¿Me recomendarías algún curso o es mejor aprender de manera autodidacta? Quisiera hacer el juego a móvil, pero no sé que tan complejo sea. De cierta manera la programación me ha asustado por la gran cantidad de lenguajes y formas de hacer las cosas. Sin embargo, no aprendes a nadar si no te echas al agua.

@NumberBinary100 puedes portar juegos de PyGame a Android, no es trivial pero tampoco muy complicado, especialmente si no requieres muchas bibliotecas externas o funcionalidades nativas. Mírate esta  pregunta si te interesa para comenzar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/610567/15089. Los dispositivos móviles suelen ser ecosistemas más cerrados, con sus propios lenguajes nativos y frameworks y Python no tiene tradicionalmente un soporte top en estas plataformas. En cuanto a aprender, el mejor consejo que siempre doy es que practiques mucho, equivocate mucho, aprende del porqué del error y sigue.

Y no hay atajos, especialmente cuidado con la IA en estos días, es una buena herramienta de apoyo pero ni sabe programar ni enseña a programar, por mucho que un interesado CEO de una compañía de GPUs diga lo contrario... :) No te preocupes por el lenguaje, los lenguajes son herramientas, cada uno mejor o peor para cada tarea concreta. Elije uno que te guste, de propósito general, multiparadigma, con buena comunidad y ecosistema de bibliotecas y recursos rico. Python no es mala opción, cuando aprendas los fundamentos de la programación aprender nuevos lenguajes o paradigmas no es tan complicado

En cuanto a cursos vs autodidacta, generalmente con cursos se suele ir más rápido al estar ya todo organizado para ti, pero depende de cada cual, hay quien aprender de forma autodidacta se vuelve una montaña y se pierde y quien los cursos y sus problemas "artificiales" les aburre y aprenden mejor por su cuenta programando cosas concretas que les interese desde un videojuegos a solventar retos matemáticos o crear apps para sus tareas cotidianas,

Yo siempre he sido muy de los segundos, unas instrucciones básicas de como nadar y a la piscina de cabeza. Si, probablemente te medio ahogues, tardes más tiempo (y por el camino aprendas algo de mantenimiento de piscinas aunque no sirva para nadar y a bucear de paso), es posible que tu estilo de natación no sea el más ortodoxo y pulcro al final..., pero es más divertido y si es divertido se aprende más y mejor :).

Wow amigo, de verdad tus palabras me inspirán. Muchas gracias por tus consejos y por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme y responde. Un abrazo desde México
